# Как сохранить состояние между переходами?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Вывожу в отдельный контейнер значения `label` для выбранныx `checkbox`'ов. Нажимаю на кнопку `применить`, страница обновляется и вывод исчезает, хотя галочки в чекбоксах стоят.

Как сделать чтобы вывод чекбоксов не исчезал между переходами?

```js
var label = $('.ctf--b-filt-check-list label'),
  checkbox = $('.ctf--b-filt-check-list :checkbox').on('change', function() {
    var checked = checkbox.filter(':checked');
    $('#log').html('Выбрано: ' + checked.length);
    var labelText = checked.map(function(i, el) {
      return label.filter('[for="' + el.id + '"]').text();
    }).get().join(',');
    $('#msg').html('Названия: ' + labelText);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ctf--b-filt-check-list">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_0" value="11772">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_0">
            <i></i> ЗУБР
        </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_1" value="11780">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_1">
            <i></i> ИСТОК
        </label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="idchkk_2_1_2" value="11785">
    <label for="idchkk_2_1_2">
            <i></i> DELTA
        </label>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="log"></div>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Comment: 1. " страница обновляется" - и что вы хотели после этого, чтобы что-то осталось?


2. Используйте $.ajax()

Comment: чекбоксы остаются выделенными  
1) т.е. я нажимаю на чекбокс => блок с названиями заполняется
2) я нажимаю на кнопку применить (или обновляю страницу) => блок с названиями исчезает 
3) я опять нажимаю на чекбокс => блок появляется с новыми и выбранными ранее элементами.

Comment: отсюда я и подумал, что блок `msg` может выводится сразу после перезагрузки